# Database for web app with multiple clients

Tags: database, angular, database-design, web-applications, google-cloud-firestore

In a real-world web app, how does one go about storing data for multiple clients/companies/customers?

Lets assume we have the following collections for one client:

```
- users
- tasks
```

How would I extent this system to a second client? Is there a standard approach?

Note: I am using Firestore (no-sql).

Answer (score 1):

We use a separate set of collections for each client.  Our data structure works really well for us and looks like this...

```
/clients/{clientId}/reportingData
/clients/{clientId}/billingData
/clients/{clientId}/privateData
```

Using security rules, we allow clients to read their reportingData and billingData collections, but not the privateData collection.

However, if you need to query data across multiple clients at the same time (for internal use, for example), then Frank's option 1 would work better, with a `clientId` field.

We do the same thing with users...

`/users/{uid}/publicProfile` (anyone can read this, only the user can write)

`/users/{uid}/userProfile` (only the user can read and write)

`/users/{uid}/privateProfile` (internal data that the user can't read or write)

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that in FireStore 'clients' is your "collection", containing a "document" for each 'client_id'. And then 'reporting_data' is a "subcollection" within each of those 'client_id' "documents"?

Comment: Yes. Exactly.  You can then create rules which allow / restrict users from accessing those details, as appropriate.

Comment: That's genius! I didn't know that was possible. Are there any drawbacks to this solution apart from the one you mentioned?

Comment: If there is, it's not one that we've encountered.  A normal noSQL database requires you to denormalise.  Cloud Firestore is (I believe) unique in the way that it handles sub-collections (with the exception of Cloud Datastore), which make data models much more powerful.  However, these limitations regarding querying across multiple parent documents is something which I hope will be possible one day

Comment: What about the financial cost (billing)? If you have say 5 clients and you request to read all documents in the 'clients' collection, does that count as 5 reads or do the subcollections and their documents somehow count towards the number of reads as well, potentially leading to 100s of billed reads just to get those 5 clients? (to clarify, in my scenario, each 'client' document contains fields as well as subcollections, but let's assume I only want to read the fields, not the subcollections, e.g. for a list of all clients).

Comment: Cloud Firestore reads are shallow, by default.  When you get the whole `clients` collection, Cloud Firestore will only return the 5 documents.  It won't return any sub-collections unless you specifically request them individually.

Comment: Does this mean you have to set up security rules for each client collection as it is added?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for implementing such a multi-tenant solution on Cloud Firestore:

1. Have all clients in a single set of collections
2. Have a separate set of collections for each client
3. Have a separate project for each client

There is no approach which is pertinently better or worse.

I recommend that you at least consider having a separate project for each client. Isolating the clients from each other, makes maintenance and (possibly future) billing a lot easier.

Having all clients in a single set of collections is also possible. You'll just have to make sure that clients can't see each other's data. Since your likely accessing the database directly from the client, [use security rules to ensure that clients can only access their own data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#security_rules_and_query_results).

Comment: What about option #2? How would I implement this in FireStore? Would you have "users_client1", "tasks_client1", "users_client2", "tasks_client2" as collection titles?