# Structure data inside a Document database

Tags: json, database, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a app that is going to serve as an agenda or a scheduling book for some services. It's planned to the app to work in a "per customer" way, Angular in the front-end and to use the new Google Firestore, for all the real time and pseudo-backendless stuff.

The question is, as I have never worked with NoSQL databases before, how should I structure the data inside Firestore?

I thought about something that would look like this:

```js
{
    //Collection
    "customer-a": {
        //Document
        "info": {
            "name": "Customer A",
            "Phones": [{
                "contact-name": "",
                "number": ""
            }],
            "address": {
                "type": "street",
                "name": "",
                "number": 0,
                "neighborhood": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "zipcode": "",
                "country": "",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": "",
                    "longitude": ""
                }
            }
        },
        //Document
        "config": {
            "active-theme": "",
            "themes": [{}]
        },
        //Document
        "customer-data": {
            //SubCollection
            "employees": {
                //Document
                "employee-a": {
                    "name": "",
                    "phone": "",
                    "rattings": [],
                    "address": {
                        "type": "street",
                        "name": "",
                        "number": 0,
                        "neighborhood": "",
                        "city": "",
                        "state": "",
                        "zipcode": "",
                        "country": ""
                    },
                    //SubCollection
                    "schedulings": {
                        //Document
                        "2017": {
                            "total": 300,
                            "scheduling": [{
                                "client": {
                                    "name": "",
                                    "phone": "",
                                    "rating": 5,
                                },
                                "price": 10,
                                "services": [{
                                    "name": "",
                                    "price": 10
                                }],
                                "datetime": "",
                            }]
                        },
                        "2018": {
                            "total": 300,
                            "scheduling": [{
                                "client": {
                                    "name": "",
                                    "phone": "",
                                    "classificacao": 5,
                                },
                                "price": 10,
                                "services": [{
                                    "name": "",
                                    "price": 10
                                }],
                                "datetime": "",
                            }]
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
            //SubCollection
            "stock": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking on splitting the scheduling into years because I think it may grow in size a lot, but as I said, I've never worked with this kind of database, so I don't really know how much data I could nest inside a document, for example...

As an exaggerated amount of data for a base calculation I thought about around 200k "objects" that would be stored for each employee per year, is that much or it's ok to store that much data nested?
Should I keep creating sub collections inside Firestore or it should be one single collections to store only different documents and nest everything?

Hope someone can help me,
Thanks.

Comment: See if my answer here solves your issue [Database for web app with multiple clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596581/database-for-web-app-with-multiple-clients)

Comment: It gave me some clarification about some things, but I still don't really know if it would be better to completely separate each customer's data in its own collections or not...

Does the collection or document have a maximum size, and does it also grow as I insert documents in it ? and what about sub collections, does it increase the document size? 

And the amount of data I mentioned is considered much or not for Firestore ?

Comment: Each document is the size of the fields that you store in it.  Sub-collections contain separate documents.  Cloud Firestore is designed to scale, so you can have millions of documents within a sub-collection.  In my opinion, having a separate collection for each client would make your application and rules difficult to work with.